# parse json data seperated by commas?

Tags: python, json, extract

Lets say i have the following json:

```
{"data":"DOG,CAT,BIRD,SEED,HEART,DRAGON,LINK,SUNSHINE","success":true}
```

How would I extract the 1st, 3rd, 6th item in "data"? So extract dog, bird, and dragon. These words will always be changing too. I know how to extract the entire thing by doing:

```
set['data']
```

But i'm not sure how to extract individually.

Comment: You'll want to call split with a comma as the arg

Comment: You need to be more specific as to what's your problem because as is, there are a million possible answers and 0 to give you at the same time. How will you know which word to extract for instance ? As they will be forever changing as you said. That being said, you might want to look at [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 1):

It is a string. You can use the split method. Assuming you have loaded it into python using json.load(), you can do this:

```
words = set['data'].split(',')
print words
```

['DOG', 'CAT', 'BIRD', 'SEED', 'HEART', 'DRAGON', 'LINK', 'SUNSHINE']

Check out the string methods to find out all the ways to manipulate them.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON into an object then split a string into an array delimited by (,) comma

```
class Example(obj):
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.__dict__ = json.loads(data)

    myObject = Example(myJSONData)
    myList = myObject.data.split(",")
    dog = myList[0]
    bird = myList[2]
    dragon = myList[5]
```